# Como exibir valores do gráfico em chartJS sem mouseover?

Tags: chartjs

```
var chartData = {
    labels: [<?php echo html_entity_decode($nomes) ?>],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Desempenho global (Todas limpezas efetuadas em <?php echo $anoAvaliado ?>)',
        data: [<?php foreach($limpezasAnuais as $limpeza){ echo $limpeza.",";} ?>],
        backgroundColor: [<?php foreach ($cores as $cor){echo "\"" . $cor . "\",";} ?>],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
}
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    showTooltips: false,
    data: {
        labels: [<?php echo html_entity_decode($nomes) ?>],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Desempenho global (Todas limpezas efetuadas em <?php echo $anoAvaliado ?>)',
            data: [<?php foreach($limpezasAnuais as $limpeza){ echo $limpeza.",";} ?>],
            backgroundColor: [<?php foreach ($cores as $cor){echo "\"" . $cor . "\",";} ?>],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {

            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: false
                }

            }]

        }
    }
});
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode user o [eventos](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html#event-option) que o ChartJS disponibiliza. Por exemplo, para que o gráfico responda apenas a eventos de clique, você pode usar:

```
options: {
        //Este gráfico não responderá ao mousemove, etc
        events: ['click']
}
```

Para deixar o `Tooltip` sempre visível na versão `ChartJs > 2.1.5` você pode controlar através das propriedade do `options`. Lembrando que você precisa registrar o plug-in antes de inicializar o gráfico.

[Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37089869/4312593)

```
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }


      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Em seguida usar

```
options: {
    showAllTooltips: true
}
```

**Exemplo**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
Chart.pluginService.register({
  beforeRender: function(chart) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      chart.pluginTooltips = [];
      chart.config.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
        chart.getDatasetMeta(i).data.forEach(function(sector, j) {
          chart.pluginTooltips.push(new Chart.Tooltip({
            _chart: chart.chart,
            _chartInstance: chart,
            _data: chart.data,
            _options: chart.options.tooltips,
            _active: [sector]
          }, chart));
        });
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  },
  afterDraw: function(chart, easing) {
    if (chart.config.options.showAllTooltips) {
      if (!chart.allTooltipsOnce) {
        if (easing !== 1)
          return;
        chart.allTooltipsOnce = true;
      }

      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = true;
      Chart.helpers.each(chart.pluginTooltips, function(tooltip) {
        tooltip.initialize();
        tooltip.update();
        tooltip.pivot();
        tooltip.transition(easing).draw();
      });
      chart.options.tooltips.enabled = false;
    }
  }
});

var data = {
  labels: ["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Meu dataset",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
    borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    borderWidth: 2,
    hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
    hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 20, 81, 56, 55, 40],
  }]
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas, {
  data: data,
  options: {
    showAllTooltips: true,
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
          return '';
        },
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
          var datasetLabel = '';
          var label = data.labels[tooltipItem.index];
          return data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart" height="230" width="680"></canvas>
```

Comment: Entendi Netinho, mas não é possível que o valor seja exibido sem eu precisar clicar e sem precisar do mouseover?  Preciso que funcione assim para sair no PDF.

Comment: @ViniciusAvanzi é possível sim. Alterei a resposta. Vê se te atente. Att.

Comment: deu certinho! Só mais uma coisa, tem como exibir somente o valor? Está exibindo os nomes e também a legenda.Queria postar o print aqui mas ainda não sei mexer direito no fórum, rsrsrsr

Comment: @ViniciusAvanzi Alterei novamente a resposta para exibir apenas o valor. Caso tenha mais dúvida, consulte a documentação do plugin: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/
Se a resposta te atender vote nela para ajudar a outra pessoas. Att.

Comment: o que você fez? Alterou o registro do plugin ? Obrigado! Como faço para votar na resposta ?

Comment: @ViniciusAvanzi eu coloquei no option a função callbacks. Para você votar como resposta aceita clica no 'v' dá resposta. Veja o print aqui: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/capturar-png-6347e280-f9dd-416e-942f-97b650b40ca1

Comment: @ViniciusAvanzi O stack tem um tour onde você poderá sanar suas dúvida como voto útil, voto de aceite para resposta, condutas e como elaborar perguntas e resposta. Segue o link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Att.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Netinho Santos. Funcionou!!! Deus te abençoe!